# Textboxes are not seperated and stacked together

Tags: android

Every time I try to run my application the two textboxes username and password are on top of each other. I went through the xml file and I am using `android:layout_below` but it still does not seem to work? Also for some reason it shows the password textbox on top of the username one where as I want it to be the other way around.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVuqD.png)
[Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBRGS.png)

Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="254dp"
    android:layout_height="221dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotellogo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="146dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="146dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="339dp"
    android:text="Guest"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="344dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usernamelogo"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="305dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/userpassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of how do you see layout in design

Comment: I've added the design view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried to help you with much more effort.

**First**, It doesn't recommend to use Relative layout, check [this article](https://medium.com/quark-works/relative-layout-is-dead-meet-constraint-layout-fa2f8a5fee08) to know more.

**Second**, use wrap_content, match_parent, etc.. and try to reduce the line of code with fixed Dp (e.g. 300dp), Because your xml won't fit all devices.

**Third**, I found you should replace your parent ViewGroup from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout or ConstraintsLayout. Since your view is pretty simple, I chose LinearLayout. 
If you don't know what's LinearLayout is? please check [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout). In brief, it would organize your view arranged according to your orientation. In this XML we use Vertical orientation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="221dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotellogo" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawable="@drawable/usernamelogo"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawable="@drawable/userpassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Guest"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

So, if you have any question regarding this solution, just reply

Happy coding